# Is it possible to use variable in meta tag?

Tags: django, web, django-templates, search-engine, meta-tags

I am new at web dev. I am using Django, and I just wonder is it possible to use variable in meta description tag, Just like this:

```
<meta name="description"
content="{{blog_detail.context_1|slice:160|safe}}">
```

Will it still appear on search engines?

Answer (score 1):

If that value is available in the context whenever that template is rendered, then yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I know it is a basic question but I am new at web dev, thanks again for your interest!